# How to SUM Duplicate COUNT values in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I have this code:

```
Const SQLExpression As String = "SELECT site.siteid AS 'SITE ID', site_name AS 'SITE',  COUNT(DISTINCT date) AS 'Attendance', 75 * (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT date) AS 'Attendance') AS 'Total' FROM record LEFT JOIN learner on record.idNumber = learner.idNumber LEFT JOIN site ON learner.siteid=site.siteid WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) GROUP BY record.idNumber "
```

And it returns the following data: [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hvNI.png)
[image]

I want to to get the following:

```
+----------+--------------------------------+
| SITE ID | SITE              | Attendance  |
+-------------------------------------------+
| 314     | Broad Market1     |    34       |
| 254     | Catherine Booth.. |    36       |
| 289     | Ceter for Entrep..|    27       |
| 330     | Climamark Morem.. |     7       |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

I have tried the following code:

```
"SELECT siteid AS 'SITE ID', site_name AS 'SITE', SUM(DISTINCT Attendance) AS 'Attendance' FROM (SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT record.date)AS 'Attendance' FROM record LEFT JOIN learner on record.idNumber = learner.idNumber LEFT JOIN site ON learner.siteid=site.siteid WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) GROUP BY record.idNumber) As Attendance, site GROUP BY siteid "
```

Am getting the following data: [TableResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8qPD.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that in the table site you have id for primary key  you should use a inner join  INNER JOIN site Attendance.siteid = site.id  (and not a cross join (Attendance, site without where)  )

```
  "SELECT siteid AS 'SITE ID'
      , site_name AS 'SITE'
      , SUM(DISTINCT Attendance) AS 'Attendance' 
  FROM (
      SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT record.date) AS 'Attendance' 
      FROM record 
      LEFT JOIN learner on record.idNumber = learner.idNumber 
      LEFT JOIN site ON learner.siteid=site.siteid 
      WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) 
      AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) 
      GROUP BY record.idNumber ) As T_Attendance
      INNER JOIN site T_Attendance.siteid = site.id
      GROUP BY siteid "
```

Comment: The column Attendance is not part of the database but is code generated form: COUNT(DISTINCT record.date)AS 'Attendance'

Comment: You have also  an Attendance as table name alias (FROM subquery).. i have updated the answer  with a more explicti alias  R_Attendance  ..